# Updating ArrayList<Object[]> within model is producing a compilation error

Tags: java, arrays, swing, arraylist

Modified a sample i found that uses a model. 
Originally the sample would only add a new record. 
The code was modified to allow editing of the fields and included the `setValueAt()` call
in order to maintain any changes. 
The data is stored within an `ArrayList` of an Object array and this is producing errors when trying to update the `ArrayList`.

When using:

```
al.set(row, value);
```

It produces the error :

```
TableWithModel.java:66: error: no suitable method found for set(int,Object)
                    al.set(row, value);
                      ^
method ArrayList.set(int,Object[]) is not applicable
  (actual argument Object cannot be converted to Object[] by method invocation conversion)
1 error
```

Tried doing a variety of different syntax but just get different errors. 
Something obvious is being overlooked but not sure what.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableWithModel extends JFrame {

    MyModel model;

    TableWithModel(Object[][] obj, String[] header) {
        super("Static JTable example");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        model = new MyModel(obj, header);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        add(panel);    // adding panel to frame
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] rowAndColumn = {
                {"Row1", "Column2"},
                {"Row2", "Column2"},
                {"Row3", "Column2"},
                {"Row4", "Column2"}
        };
        String[] header = {"Column1", "Column2"};
        TableWithModel twm = new TableWithModel(rowAndColumn, header);
    }

    class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        ArrayList<Object[]> al;
        String[] header;

        MyModel(Object[][] obj, String[] header) {
            this.header = header;
            al = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
            for(int i = 0; i < obj.length; ++i)
                al.add(obj[i]);
        }
        public int getRowCount() {
            return al.size();
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return header.length;
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return al.get(rowIndex)[columnIndex];
        }

        public String getColumnName(int index) {
            return header[index];
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
        { return true; }

        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
            al.set(row, value);
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ArrayList` variable `al` holds *arrays* of objects. To update the object array element at column `col` stored at index `row` in the `ArrayList`, you need to use the following:

```
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
    al.get(row)[col] = value;
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
}
```

`al.get(row)[col] = value;` is a shorthand for the following:

```
Object[] data = al.get(row);
data[col] = value;
```

This is similar to what's already implemented in the `getValueAt` method except that you're setting the array element instead of retrieving it.

The reason why `al.set(row, value);` does not compile is that the `set` method expects the second argument to be an `Object[]` array, and not an `Object`, since that's what the `ArrayList` holds.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. 
Ran a quick test and it works. 
What is a bit strange is call "get" instead of "set".

Shortly after posting I was able to find a solution using "set"

```
           Object[] data = al.get(row);
           data[col] = value;
           al.set(row, data);
```

It makes sense using the set but what is it that makes it work in your example using "get"?

Comment: This would work but no need for `al.set(row, data);`. The statement `al.get(row)[col] = value;` is exactly equivalent to `Object[] data = al.get(row); data[col] = value;`.